# Find $(a,b)$ for $\gcd(a,b) = 13$. I think the book is wrong here.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

$49a - 125b = 169$

$a = 125k + 6$

$b = 49k + 1$

$a$ and $b$ are *natural*

$\gcd(a,b) = d$

The question says: Find what $\gcd(a,b)$ could be then find $a$ and $b$ where their $\gcd$ is equal to $13$.

My solution:

Of course, $d$ possibilities is going to be $169$ divisors by applying division properties.

So $d$ is $\left \{ 1,13,169 \right \}$

What I don't understand is how the book found $a$ and $b$

The book found $a$ and $b$ like this:

$d = 13$ $\Rightarrow$ $\left\{\begin{matrix}
b= 0\pmod {13}
\\ 
a = 0 \pmod {13}
\end{matrix}\right.$

\begin{Bmatrix}
125k + 6 = 0\pmod {13}
\\ 
49k + 1 = 0 \pmod {13}
\end{Bmatrix}

So: $125k + 6 - 49k - 1 = 0\pmod {13}$

In the end we find $k = 9\pmod {13}$ which is $k = 13m + 9$ where $k$ is a natural number. Then by putting this in $a$ and $b$ we find:

$a = 1625m + 1131$

$b = 637m + 442$

where $m$ is a natural number.

I understand almost all this and I know this way.

What I don't understand is I don't think this way should be correct. Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't $a, b = 0\pmod {13}$ for $d = 13$ only work when $13$ is the highest number in the possibilities? But here it isn't $13$ it is $169$ so I don't think it works.

Because $a,b$ can be divided by $13$ and $169$ at same time this way. So if $169$ is a divisor of both then it's already the $\gcd$ not $13$ since $13$ is a divisor of $169$ so if $a$ and $b$ were multiples of $169$ they will be both $0 \pmod {13}$ even though their $\gcd$ is going to be $169$

TL;DR: I don't think $a, b = 0\pmod {13}$ should work here and I think the book is wrong. If I'm wrong, can you explain it to me please?

Comment: The question is to take it as a *given* that $\gcd(a,b)=13$ and that $\gcd(a,b) \ne 1$ and $\gcd(a,b)\ne 169$.

Comment: @fleablood But they didn't say that in the book. They only said "find $a$ and $b$ for $GCD(a, b) = 13$"

Comment: "They only said "find a and b for GCD(a,b)=13""  Yes.... so they said (and *YOU* quoted it) $\gcd(a,b) = 13$.  It is a given.

Comment: @fleablood I'm not a native English speaker. I thought that was the correct translation but it seems that I'm wrong. The way it's written in the book implies that we have to find $a$ and $b$ in a way so that their $GCD = 13$

Comment: You do know that $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ or $\gcd(a,b) = 13$ or $\gcd(a,b) = 169$.  You were correct.  And if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ you will get some answers.  And if $\gcd(a,b)=13$ you will get different answers.  And if $\gcd(a,b)=169$ you will get different answer.  The book did (and most certianly *DID* say) to find the answer for when $\gcd(a,b)=13$.

Comment: @fleablood But how do you know that it doesn't want us to find $a$ and $b$ so that their $GCD = 13$? Like, they have 3 $GCD$ possibilities but out of these 3, the book wants us to find $a$ and $b$ in a way where $GCD$ is always $13$

Comment: That's the exact same thing.  They want you find $a,b$ where $\gcd(a,b)= 13$.  If $\gcd(a,b)=13$ what can $a,b$ be?  What $a,b$ will result in $\gcd(a,b)$?  Those are two ways of asking the exact same question.

Comment: Please quote the *complete* question statement *exactly* as it is stated in the source. Without such if makes it difficult (if not impossible)  to determine what is intended.

Comment: @fleablood But if we apply their way, $a$ and $b$ = 0 (mod 13), that means there is a chance these $a$ and $b$ we found have $GCD = 169$ because $13$ is a divisor of $169$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP is correct in having  concerns about the answer $$a = 1625m + 1131, b = 637m + 442.$$
In particular, there is nothing in the method shown that prevents $a$ and $b$ from having a gcd of $169$.

In fact, if $m=7$ then $a$ and $b$ do have gcd $169$. So, the correct answer must state 'for $m\ne 13l+7$'.

To see this, consider the numbers $\frac{a}{13}=49m+34$ and $\frac{b}{13}=125a+87$. We are interested in when both of these numbers are divisible by $13$.

Working modulo $13$ the numbers are $10m+8$ and $8m+9$ and it is now easy to see that $m= 7$ makes both expressions multiples of $13$. Then any $m$ of the form $13l+7$ would do just as well.

Comment: Exactly like I thought! Thanks but is there a method without trying/testing numbers for $m$? Also may I ask how did you find $m$ must not be $13l+7$?

Comment: Yes. If you divide each of the answers for $a,b$  by $13$ you get $49m+34$ and $125a+87$. Modulo $13$ these are $10m+8$ and $8m+9$ and it is now easy to see that $m=7$ (mod 13) makes both expressions multiples of $13$.

Comment: I've added this to the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is via the first equation solving.

If $\;d=13,\;$ then
$$a=13x,\quad b=13y,\quad 49x-125y=13,$$
$$x_1=x-2y,\quad 49x_1-27y=13,$$
$$y_1=y-x_1=3y-x,\quad 22x_1–27y_1=13,$$
$$x_2=x_1-y_1=2x-5y,\quad 22x_2-5y_1=13,$$
$$y_2=y_1-4x_2=23y-9x,\quad 2x_2-5y_2=13,$$
$$x_3=x_2-2y_2=20x-51y,\quad 2x_3-y_2=13,$$
\begin{cases}
20x-51y=m+6\\[4pt]
-9x+23y=2m-1,
\end{cases}
$$x=\begin{vmatrix}
m+6 & -51\\ 2m-1 & 23
\end{vmatrix}=87+125m,\quad 
y=\begin{vmatrix}
20 & m+6\\ -9& 2m-1
\end{vmatrix}=34+49m,\quad m\in\mathbb N,$$
$$a=13(87+125m),\quad b=13(34+49m),\quad m\in\mathbb N.$$

And from the overdefined system
\begin{cases}
13(87+125m)=125k+6\\[4pt]
13(34+49m)=49k+1
\end{cases}
should $\;k=13m+9.\;$

If $\;d=169,\;$ then similarly
$$a=169x,\quad b=169y,\quad 49x-125y=1,\dots$$
\begin{cases}
20x-51y=m\\[4pt]
-9x+23y=2m-1,
\end{cases}
$$x=\begin{vmatrix}
m & -51\\ 2m-1 & 23
\end{vmatrix}=125m-51,\quad 
y=\begin{vmatrix}
20 & m\\ -9 & 2m-1
\end{vmatrix}=49m-20,\quad m\in\mathbb N,$$
$$a=169(125m-51),\quad b=169(49m-20),\quad m\in\mathbb N.$$

And from the overdefined system
\begin{cases}
169(125m-51)=125k+6\\[4pt]
169(49m-20)=49k+1
\end{cases}
should $\;k=169m+69.\;$